# How to add new line based on existing word in Notepad++ Using Regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am looking to add a new line based the existing word in Notepad++ using regex.
For example , I have below files with multiple create table statements and i need to add "drop table if exists  " .

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( ) ;
CREATE TABLE table2 ( ) ;
CREATE TABLE table3 ( ) ;
CREATE TABLE table4 ( ) ;
```

I am looking for output as below .Here Table names are different .

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 ( ) ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
CREATE TABLE table2 ( ) ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table3;
CREATE TABLE table3 ( ) ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table4;
CREATE TABLE table4 ( ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Find

```
CREATE TABLE (\w*) \( \) ;
```

and replace it with

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \1;\nCREATE TABLE (\1) \( \) ;\n
```

Be sure to set the Search Mode to Regular expression.

[image]

How does this work? The `(\w*)` defines a capture group which you can refer to in the replacement with `\1`. As you can see, you can even refer to them multiple times. Note that the parentheses later in the regex, `\( \)`, are escaped with backslashes, because they are *not* capture groups.

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks a lot for your help ! @Glorfindel.

Comment: @Praveen if one of the answers helped you, don’t forget to upvote and accept the answer, as that’s the way to show appreciation in the Stackexchange sites

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `CREATE TABLE (\w+) \( \) ;`
- Replace with: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $1;\n$0`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
CREATE TABLE    # Literally
(\w+)           # group 1, 1 or more word character (the table name)
\( \) ;         # parentheses, have to be escaped as they have special meaning in regex
```

**Replacement:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS    # literally
$1                      # content of group 1, the table name
;                       # semicolon
\n                      # linefeed, you can use \r\n for windows EOL
$0                      # content of group 0, the whole match (CREATE TABLE ...)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]